# Android use shape to create button

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, android-button

Hey I am currently having problems creating nice looking buttons via xml on Android.
I am currently using PNG files as buttons which works pretty well, but I want to save some memory so I thought about creating the button looks in the xml file which works pretty well so far.

The only problem is, that I don't know how to put a color in the center of the shape. With   android:centerColor I only change the color in the vertical middle of the button, but I want to make the button seem more plastic so I need to have sth like an inner, brighter circle in the middle of the button.

In the image I attached, you see, what the button currently looks like (left) and what I want to achieve (right). Both of the buttons are made by myself, but of course, the right one with photoshop and not by xml.

http://img.flashtux.org/img1332cc51010ax1c217432.jpg

The code I use to create the button is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>

            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ef0000"
                android:endColor="#993119"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#661014" />
            <corners
                android:radius="9dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
           </shape>
           </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `android:type="radial"` on your gradient element on XML.

Comment: Your post improved the quality of my life enormously.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your shape to be more complex you should forget about xml Drawables and create your own stateful Drawable (class Foo extends Drawable)